# Error: GraphQL error: The server does not support SSL connections

Tags: node.js, angular, postgresql, graphql

I am trying to do further development on a existing GraphQL application using my local postgreSQL database and angular. The DB is up and running as well as the Backend on my local computer. However when I attempt to login to the app or sign up or do anything that sends anything to the database I get this error:

Error: GraphQL error: The server does not support SSL connections

It works fine if I use the production server and live database. I tried installing OpenSSL and adding these lines to the postgressql.conf however still doesn't work:

```
ssl = on
ssl_ca_file = 'E:/Work/SSL/certs'
ssl_cert_file = 'E:/Work/SSL/certsserver.crt'
#ssl_crl_file = ''
ssl_key_file = 'E:/Work/SSL/certsserver.key'
```

any help would be appreciated.